# How to add '%' symbol in textbox using jsf and jsp?

Tags: jsp, jsf, jsf-2

I am new to jsp and jsf. I want to insert '%' symbol in textbox. But I am not able to insert % symbol in textbox using jsp and jsf.

My jsf code is :

```
<h:inputText class="form-control input-sm input-element"
                                    id="oligoName" name="name" maxlength="30" placeholder="" />
```

My jsp code is :

```
<input type="text" class="form-control input-sm input-element"
    id="Name" maxlength="30" name="name" placeholder="">
```

I have a html code for the same. Based on that only I gave class.

All other symbols can be inserted in textbox. Issue is only with '%' symbol.

Can someone please help me out?

Comment: When I removed the class mentioned (form-control input-sm input-element), the issue remains same. So I think its nothing related to class.

Comment: Elaborate "I am not able" in developer's perspective not in enduser's perspective.

Comment: @BalusC The development is done.
When I tested in UI, I faced this issue:

In UI, when I tried to enter the value "JINCE%XYZ" in textbox, the '%' is not getting entered in textbox. I am only able to enter "JINCEXYZ", % is not getting printed in textbox.

Comment: On reading the question looks like some client side scripting is doing something keypress event I guess.  Can you try debugging the javascript code?

Comment: It's hard to say that that is a JSF problem, Jince. By the time you're on the browser, the only thing running is HTML, Javascript, and CSS, so the only thing that could be preventing you from typing '%' is Javascript or a computer issue. Are you running some Javascript you haven't told us about?

Comment: Ya I am using javascript. Let me check whether the issue with js or not
No issues with computer. I am able to enter % in textarea.
Thanks all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the issue. As @Himanshu Bhardwaj @DavidS told, the issue was with the javascript.
There was an event 'keypress', which suppressed us from entring '%'. 
I unbind that event as :

```
$('#Name').unbind('keypress');
```

Thank you all

Answer (score -1):

There are several approaches for achieving this.

1. Initialize the backing input variable with "%". It's an ugly solution, that involves manual value validation and keeping appearing/ignoring the symbol.
2. Set the symbol with Javascript manually. Almost the same as above but on client side level.
3. Use a JSF AJAX extension like Primefaces and Primefaces Extensions. The last one in particular has inputNumber element that supports prefixes and suffixes (http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-ext/sections/inputNumber/basicUsage.jsf). Alternatively the original Primefaces provides inputMask element that does essentially the same but in a more generic way (http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/inputMask.xhtml).
4. The solution I personally prefer. Show the "%" symbol after the inputText as text leaving the input field empty to do what it's supposed to. This can be done using simple DIVs and CSS formatting.

Comment: Try reading question and comments from top to bottom instead of only the title. This whole answer makes no utter sense.